# ScrollBars for tabs in JTabbedPane not working for other systems - Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, windowbuilder

This is what i do to add tabs to tabbedpane

```
tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);

        panel = new Panel(this);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 0));
        panel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(10, 10));
        GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(this);
        groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(Alignment.TRAILING, groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
        .addComponent(tabbedPane, Alignment.LEADING, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 850, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addComponent(panel, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 850, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addGap(88))
        );
        groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addComponent(panel, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
    .addComponent(tabbedPane, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 676, groupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        .addContainerGap(14, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        panela= new panelb(this);
        JScrollPane scrollPane_panela = new JScrollPane(panela);
            tabbedPane.addTab("Birth History", null, scrollPane_panela, null);
        setLayout(groupLayout);

        panelb= new panleb(this);
           JScrollPane scrollPane_panleb = new JScrollPane(panleb);
           tabbedPane.addTab("Headache History", null, scrollPane_panleb, null);
        setLayout(groupLayout);

        panelc= new panelc(this);
        JScrollPane scrollPane_Tpanelc = new JScrollPane(panelc);   
        tabbedPane.addTab("Treatment History", null, scrollPane_panelc, null);
        setLayout(groupLayout);
```

I'm using Group Layout. I didn't set any preferred size, minimum size or size.
I could Scroll only in my system 
when i try to run this application in other system . I couldn't scroll.

the size in add component is what is giving out the problem

Any suggestions would be great help

Comment: Is there any Exception? Please share a minimal testable code.

Comment: no, when i change the preferred size in the addcomponent method to default size,tabbedpane disappears i couldn't figure out exactly what is causing it. sorry

Comment: Sorry but it's not a testable code. I can't help you.

Comment: .addComponent(tabbedPanel, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE). This is what is causing error i feel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the response. The problem is I've added tabbedpane to splitpane where the bounds was set manually. when i removed that bounds to let the layout manager to find out the preferred size. Things are working fine